# 'FuseIT SFDC Explorer' tool for importing WSDL(with multiple import, include tag and XSD files)

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to import a WSDL in FuseIT tool which has multiple nesting of XSD and other WSDLs in it. I have a folder with all XSD and WSDL files. Now I want to remove nesting from WSDL and combine all data in one file in order to use it in Salesforce. I want to remove import, include and binding tags from WSDL. Can anybody suggest me how to do it?

Comment: This question would probably be better suited to the Salesforce StackExchange site - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thank you. I will put this on salesforce.stackexchange.com